# Is there a way to name a function and class the same thing in python?

Tags: python, numpy, module

I'm working on a module and I want the user to be able to use both a(x) (function "a") and a.b(x) (class "a" with function "b"), but Python doesn't seem to let me do that. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Why do you want such thing?

Comment: Classes already are functions: they create an instance when you call them. What are you actually trying to do with these hypothetical calls you want to use?

Comment: Also, naming convention is to have class name Capitalized. having a instance name same as a function is not possible. In any case it's up to the user/programmer who will use your API to choose the name of the instance.

Comment: You can't do it. A name can only name one thing in a particular scope. Either it names a class (which is also a function that creates its instances) or a function.

Comment: @buran It's not an instance, `a.b` is a method named `b` in the class `a`, analogous with `re.sub()`.

Comment: Essentially I created a function called psi.x() which gets the position operator of a Wavefunction, and I also want to create psi.x.expVal() and psi.x.sigma() which get expectation values and the sigma of the Wavefunction, respectively

Comment: @barmar, if I understand that you point to the case where they call the method directly. My understandig was that OP refers to `a` as instance of the class. That's why I refer to naming convention of the class. And I think `re.sub()` is the module-level function, not calling method of the class.

Comment: @buran He said 'class "a" with function "b"", not 'instance "a" with function "b"'. But it could be a terminology error.

Comment: @buran Turns out that `re` fooled me, because the `SRE_Pattern` class has methods that mirror the module functions, e.g. `re.compile('xxx').search(...)` == `re.search('xxx', ...)`

Comment: @Barmar, it's possible to have functions that have the same name as an instance's method.  `numpy` does that all the time.  In `numpy` the function usually delegates the action to the corresponding method.  `np.sum(x, axis=1)` and `x.sum(axis=1)` do the same thing if `x` is a numpy array.

Comment: @hpaulj Of course, since they're different namespaces.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
class Func:
    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.b(x)

    def b(self, x):
        return x ** 2

a = Func()

print(a(2))
print(a.b(2))
```

Eseentially you overload the call operator to make the object callable, and in this case you just call the desired function `b` inside the object.

Voila, and you have achieved what you wanted.

Comment: If you found this useful, then please up-vote and accept it as an answer.